# ExtJs fieldLabel not showing in tabPanel

Tags: extjs

As soon as I move a form field to a tabPanel item, the field label doesn't show:

```
items: [{
    xtype:'tabpanel',
    plain:true,
    activeTab: 0,
    height:235,
    defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name:'limit',  
            fieldLabel:'Limit'
        }]
    },{
        title: 'Tab 2',
        items: []
    }]
}]
```

Any suggestions how to make the label render?

You can first try your answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/UgLN4/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the following line to the definition of the "Tab 1"

`layout:'form'`

If you look closely at the documentation:

> fieldLabel : String
>
> The label text to display next to this Component (defaults to '').
> Note: this config is only used when this Component is rendered by a Container which
> has been configured to use the FormLayout layout manager (e.g. Ext.form.FormPanel or specifying layout:'form').

Comment: Well spotted! You are a genius.